# why does my craftsman riding mower not work in 2 3 and 4th gear?

Tags: gears, lawnmower, craftsman

why does my craftsman riding mower not go into 2 3 or 4th gear?it will go into low gears but not the high gears. is it my pulley or my belts or what? i have replaced the transmission and it still is not working.

Comment: This is very broad - what have you checked regarding your pulley and belts? And do you mean it only goes into 1st gear? Which parts of the transmission were replaced?

Comment: When you say "*go into 2 3 or 4th gear*", do you mean it physically will not allow you to shift into those gears? Or you can shift into those gears, but it won't move? Also, telling us what model of Craftsman riding mower you have would be very helpful. Not all of them are the same.

Comment: Which model Craftsman is this?